# How to design entity structures using Google App Engine Datastore for this particular situation?

Tags: java, entity-framework, google-app-engine, data-modeling, google-cloud-datastore

OK, Here is my need. I want to build a web app using Google App Engine Datastore as backend database.

The app allows user to register an account for free. When each registered user can have a saving account, they can deposit or withdraw money in their saving account.

Using the information in this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities

I came up these code

```
public class RegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();


        Entity user = new Entity("User");
        user.setProperty("name",name);
        user.setProperty("email",email);
        user.setProperty("pass",pass);


        datastore.put(user);
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        DatastoreService ds=DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        double credit=request.getParameter("credit");
        double debit=request.getParameter("debit");

        int userKeyInt=0;
        Query q=new Query ("User");
        PreparedQuery pq=ds.prepare(q);
        for (Entity u1:pq.asIterable()){
           String emailStr=u1.getProperty("Email").toString();
           String userIDStr=u1.getProperty("UserID").toString();
           String passStr=u1.getProperty("Pass").toString();
           if(emailStr.equals(email) && passStr.equals(pass)) {
                 userKeyInt=Integer.parseInt(userIDStr);
           }
        }
        Key userKey=KeyFactory.createKey("User", userKeyInt);
        try{
           Entity user = ds.get(key);

           Entity savingAccount=new Entity ("SavingAccount");
           savingAccount.setProperty("UserID",  user.getKey());
           savingAccount.setProperty("Debit",debit);
           savingAccount.setProperty("Credit",credit);


         }

         catch (EntityNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }


    }
}
```

So the Savingaccount has the field "UserID" that plays a role of foreign key.

```
Entity user = new Entity("User");
Entity savingAccount=new Entity ("SavingAccount");
savingAccount.setProperty("UserID",  user.getKey());
```

But I am not sure what I am doing is right because there is no way to check the foreing key constraint, do we need to have **Modeling Entity Relationships** as stated in this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling?

If I do need **Modeling Entity Relationships**, then how to do it?

**Note:** Each user can have many Saving Accounts.

Comment: NB1: Do not call `toString()` when calling `getProperty` - use cast. Otherwise you will never know if you made a mistake and stored the wrong data type in a property.

Comment: NB2: It's very inefficient to loop through all users. Use a query to find one user with the right email.

Comment: NB3: Why do you store UserID as a property in User entity? Use IDs auto-generated by the Datastore. Also, IDs are stored as Long values - using integers may lead to problems.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, you said "It's very inefficient to loop through all users. Use a query to find one user with the right email.", so what should I do? Ok, we know that email is unique, then how to get user object when provided email?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, also, I do not store UserID as a property in User entity, but I do store UserID as a property of SavingAccount entity so that it is similar to Relational Database

Comment: This line `String userIDStr=u1.getProperty("UserID").toString();` applies to a user entity. If you want to get an ID from an entity, you should do `long userId = entity.getKey().getId()`.

Comment: If `email` property is indexed (it already is in your code), you can simply query User entity by email. Look at query filters: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make SavingAccountEntity a child entity of a UserEntity. It may become useful as you may decide to update your entities in a transaction to preserve data integrity.

With this approach you can retrieve all saving accounts owned by a user with a simple ancestor query on SavingAccountEntity.

Comment: Is it effective to do like this "**Entity user = new Entity("User", "tom@gmail.com");**". We directlly use email as the ID of user. If we do like that, then is it slower than if we use "Use IDs auto-generated by the Datastore"

Comment: In this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3i2BXq4Exw&list=PLjRJFNWV27juPRBp_x04hfaRrrKVex-hb) at **36:25**, we can see this code "**Entity ikai=new Entity("User","ijai@gmail.com")**". SO I think use email as UserID is ok

Comment: alos, what about Many-to-Many Relationship, how do we manage Many-to-Many Relationship? I saw this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships but not sure it is the right one

Comment: Using email as a user ID is a bad idea, in my opinion, as users tend to change their emails over time. It creates a lot of challenges - changing ID will result in a totally new key.

Comment: Maybe not email but what about using "UserName" instead of "Email"? And How to design the datastore structure if we got Many to Many Relationship. For example, **each contractor can work for many companies & each company can have many contractors**?

Comment: Username is fine - you can use it to create User entity instead of IDs. As for many-to-many, there are several different approaches, and choosing the right one depends on your expected usage patterns (i.e. kind of queries you expect to run most frequently).

Comment: For Many-to-Many relationship, can i do like this ? "**contractor.setProperty("companyID", comID); company.setProperty("contractorID", contractorID)**" just like we do in Relational Database

Comment: Yes, but typically you don't need both.

Comment: I heard that "**Non-ancestor queries are always eventually consistent , not strong consistent**". So, use filter query to get the email & check if it is not unique is not safe since while we are checking another user maybe is importing / updating data

Comment: Other users updating their accounts have no impact on entities already stored in the datastore. Eventual consistency impacts only newly created/updated entity and, typically, for less than a second.

Comment: What if 2 new users insert the same email at the same time? Then we will have a trouble right. There is a proper way to do it, please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553216/app-engine-errors-when-trying-to-insert-many-entities-in-bulk-with-condition-tha/34556628#34556628

Comment: This is right way to filter email for strongly consistent: Key personKey=KeyFactory.createKey("Person", "personName");
  
  Filter propertyNameFilter =
      new FilterPredicate(propertyName,
                          FilterOperator.EQUAL,
                          value);
  Query q = new Query(entityName, personKey).setAncestor(personKey).setFilter(propertyNameFilter);

Comment: And what if a user enters an email address he does not own? Then a legitimate owner will not be able to add it. There are many more scenarios to consider that go beyond the scope of this question. You want to make emails unique, you have to verify them.

Comment: That is a different topic. But you can force user to validate their registration by login their emails that they have just used to register.

Comment: If you verify emails, what is the probability that two different users verify the same email within a second of each other? Zero.