# App Engine Errors when trying to insert many entities in bulk with condition that property "UserNo" increases by 1 everytime an entity's inserted

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, nosql

I want to insert many user entities in bulk. User entity has property **Name** & **UserNo**. The requirement is that the property **UserNo** will automatically increase by 1 every time a User entity was inserted.

The following code works fine if I try to insert 1 record at a time.

```
public void insertUser(String name){
    Entity userEntity=new Entity("User");
    long maxID=Utility.getPropertyMaxID("User", "UserNo")+1;
    userEntity.setProperty("Name",name);
    datastore.put(userEntity); 
}

public static long getPropertyMaxID(String entityName, String propertyName){
        // Order alphabetically by property name:
        Query q = new Query(entityName)
                        .addSort(propertyName, SortDirection.DESCENDING);

        List<Entity> results = datastore.prepare(q)
                .asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
        if(results.size()>0){
            Entity e=results.get(0);
            long maxID=(Long)e.getProperty(propertyName);
            return maxID;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }

}
```

However, if I try to insert many entities at once

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    insertUser(names[i]);
}
```

Then, when checking data I can see the name got inserted correctly. However, the **UserNo** got messed up as it did not increase 1 by 1 correctly.

So, I think this could be the "**Eventual consistency**" of Google App Engine datastore because the data takes time to be inserted so the program may take the `maxUserNo` incorrectly.

So, what should I do? Should not not to use "**UserNo**"?

I did try Transaction, but it didn't work anyway

```
public void insertUser(String name){
     Transaction tx=datastore.beginTransaction();
     try{
        Entity userEntity=new Entity("User");
        long maxID=Utility.getPropertyMaxID("User", "UserNo")+1;
        userEntity.setProperty("Name",name);
        datastore.put(userEntity); 
        tx.commit();}
     catch (Exception ex){ ex.printStackTrace()};
}
```

**So, what is the best solution for this?**

Note: I heard that "**Non-ancestor queries are always eventually consistent**". SO the query inside `getPropertyMaxID` method is not Strongly consistent.

**Extra**: what about if I make a fake Person and force all Users to be children of that person & then make Ancestor query on all Users. Loop though all users to check the email for example? See this code:

```
Entity personEntity=new Entity("Person", "Tom");
Key personKey=personEntity.getKey();
Entity userEntity=new Entity("User", userName);
userEntity.setProperty("Email", email);
datastore.put(userEntity);
```

Then make a function to check the unique email

```
public static boolean checkUniqueEmail(String email){
Entity personEntity = new Entity("Person", "Tom");
        Key personKey = personEntity.getKey();

        Query query = new Query("User")
        .setAncestor(personKey);  


        List<Entity> results = datastore.prepare(query)
                       .asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());

        for(Entity e : results){

            String em=(String)e.getProperty("Email");
             if(e.equals(email)) return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown how Utility.getPropertyMaxID() works.  You don't appear to be updating the incremented number any where,  secondly eventual consistency only affects queries, not get's, so you thats not likely to be the problem.  Last consider why you need incrementing user numbers.  This will cause you problems in the future, you will need to synchronise the incrementing of this value across multiple parallel instances, which doesn't tend to perform well and is generally complicated.

Comment: @TimHoffman, 
I updated my question, please read. Second, suppose that I want to make sure email property to be unique, so I will query to check if that email is unique. But non-ancestor query is eventually & not strongly consistent. How to solve this problem?

Comment: One way is to use the email as the key - though this means if someone where to change the email - you would have to recreate all of the records (ie if they have children).  By doing this you can use a get by key (being the email address).   This is one approach.  Not sure how the UserNo idea was ever going to help you ensure a unique email address.  Why do you need a incrementing UserNo ?  I think you may be conflating a few different things here.

Comment: @TimHoffman About, email? what about if I make a fake Person and force all Users to be children of that person & then make Ancestor query on all Users. Loop though all users to check the email for example? Since Ancestor query is always give Strong consistent. Is it a good practice to do that?

Comment: I think that would be a bad idea.  You know limit yourself to 1 write/sec for everything in that entity group.

Comment: If you don't want the primary entity for the user to have the email as the id, create another entity using the email as the key and keyproperty referring to the owner. Then you just get(Key(Email, id="some@email.address")) and you have the most efficient way to check for uniqueness.

Comment: @TimHoffman, cool, but can you tell me how entity User can refer to entity Email in One-to-One Relationship?

Comment: Not sure how you would do it Java.  Depends on the toolkit. In Python the email entity would have a key property which holds the key of the user details.  This can then be retrieved with a get() from the email entity to the UserInfo and query from the userinfo -> Email entity though you could also store the email in the UserInfo. to save a query and you will probably use it a lot.

Comment: Entity emailEntity = new Entity("Email", specificEmail); Key emailKey=emailEntity.getKey(); Entity userEntity=new Entity("User", emailKey); By doing that we can make User entity to be a child of Email entity. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @TimHoffman, then I am asking myself, why Google App engine provides Transaction if Transaction could not wait to get the latest data?

Comment: What you have done doesn't help as you would need to know all ancestors of all EmailEntities.  The Email object can't have the an ancestor.  Given just an email address you want to ensure that it is unique.  Transactions are there to provide consistency, ie all commit or fail and prevent out of order updates.  Queries are not consistent without an ancestor. Thats why I mentioned using get operation to check for unique email.

Comment: @TimHoffman, I found the answer, you can read my below answer. Interestingly, that solution is similar to my solution mentioned above "*what about if I make a fake Person and force all Users to be children of that person & then make Ancestor query on all Users.*"

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

Check [this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency)

To understand how to structure your data for strong consistency, compare two different approaches for the guestbook example application from the App Engine Getting Started exercise. The first approach creates a new root entity for each greeting:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;

Entity greeting = new Entity("Greeting");
// No parent key specified, so Greeting is a root entity.

greeting.setProperty("user", user);
greeting.setProperty("date", date);
greeting.setProperty("content", content);
```

It then queries on the entity kind Greeting for the ten most recent greetings.

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;

DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Query query = new Query("Greeting")
                    .addSort("date", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);

List<Entity> greetings = datastore.prepare(query)
                                  .asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(10));
```

However, because we are using a non-ancestor query, the replica used to perform the query in this scheme may not have seen the new greeting by the time the query is executed. Nonetheless, nearly all writes will be available for non-ancestor queries within a few seconds of commit. For many applications, a solution that provides the results of a non-ancestor query in the context of the current user's own changes will usually be sufficient to make such replication latencies completely acceptable.

If strong consistency is important to your application, an alternate approach is to write entities with an ancestor path that identifies the same root entity across all entities that must be read in a single, strongly-consistent ancestor query:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;

String guestbookName = req.getParameter("guestbookName");
Key guestbookKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Guestbook", guestbookName);
String content = req.getParameter("content");
Date date = new Date();

// Place greeting in same entity group as guestbook
Entity greeting = new Entity("Greeting", guestbookKey);
greeting.setProperty("user", user);
greeting.setProperty("date", date);
greeting.setProperty("content", content);
You will then be able to perform a strongly-consistent ancestor query within the entity group identified by the common root entity:

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;

DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Key guestbookKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Guestbook", guestbookName);
Query query = new Query("Greeting", guestbookKey)
                    .setAncestor(guestbookKey)
                    .addSort("date", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);

List<Entity> greetings = datastore.prepare(query)
                                  .asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(10));
```

This approach achieves strong consistency by writing to a single entity group per guestbook, but it also limits changes to the guestbook to no more than 1 write per second (the supported limit for entity groups). If your application is likely to encounter heavier write usage, you may need to consider using other means: for example, you might put recent posts in a memcache with an expiration and display a mix of recent posts from the memcache and the Datastore, or you might cache them in a cookie, put some state in the URL, or something else entirely. The goal is to find a caching solution that provides the data for the current user for the period of time in which the user is posting to your application. Remember, if you do a get, an ancestor query, or any operation within a transaction, you will always see the most recently written data.

Comment: Except this doesn;t address how you will ensure a unque constraint on an email address.

Comment: @TimHoffman, we have to use Transaction as well. At the time we set "**Transaction tx=datastore.beginTransaction();**", the function will record the last inserting/updating time. Then in the try & catch we check the email and make sure if unique. If there is another record got inserted or updated while doing the transaction, the system will record the latest inserting/updating time. At the end of transaction the function, the function checks & compares the old & latest  inserting/updating time. If they are different then the transaction got canceled.